# Android Studio MediaRecorder won't record

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

I trying to build an audio recorder in the android studio. I followed this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XANjoeEeQ1Y

Which did not work for me? When I pushed the "record" button, nothing happened.

Therefrom I added action listeners with onClick() methods and such. Still didn't work. Then I added a text view to show me the status for debugging purpose.

After adding the status textView I found out that the beginRecording() method goes straight to the catch statement.

I watched another youtube video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lWaypoRVfSc
which seems to do more or less the same thing regarding the MediaRecorder.

So.. My question is. What have I done wrong? How can I make it actually record when the RECORD button is pushed?

Thank you in advance.

Here comes my code:

```
package com.example.natalie.recorder;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MediaPlayer mediaPLayer;
    private MediaRecorder recorder;
    private String OUTPUT_FILE;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Button startR = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
        Button stopR = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finishBtn);
        Button playRecording = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
        Button stopPlaying = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopBtn);
        final TextView statusTV;
        statusTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusTextView);

        OUTPUT_FILE= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/audiorecorder.3gpp";

        /*------START BUTTON------*/

        startR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final TextView stv=statusTV;
                try {
                    beginRecording();
                    stv.setText("Recording");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
                    String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
                    stv.setText("Error");
                }
            }
        });

        /*------STOP BUTTON------*/

        stopR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final TextView stv=statusTV;
                try {
                    stopRecording();
                    stv.setText("Stopped");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
                    String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
                    statusTV.setText("Error");
                    Log.d("here","dd",e);
                }
            }
        });

        playRecording.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    playRecording();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
                    String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
                    statusTV.setText("Error");
                }
            }
        });

        stopPlaying.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    stopPlayback();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
                    String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
                    statusTV.setText("Error");
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void stopPlayback() throws Exception{
        if(mediaPLayer != null)
            mediaPLayer.stop();
    }
    private void playRecording() throws IOException {
        ditchMediaPLayer();
        mediaPLayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPLayer.setDataSource(OUTPUT_FILE);
        mediaPLayer.prepare();
        mediaPLayer.start();

    }

    private void ditchMediaPLayer() {
        if (mediaPLayer != null) {
            try{
                mediaPLayer.release();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        if(recorder != null)
            recorder.stop();
    }
    private void beginRecording() throws Exception{
        ditchMediaRecorder();
        File outFile = new File(OUTPUT_FILE);

        if (outFile.exists()) {
            outFile.delete();
        }

        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        record.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);  
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(OUTPUT_FILE);
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    }

    private void ditchMediaRecorder() {
        if(recorder != null)
            recorder.release();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The AndroidManifest look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.natalie.recorder">



        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" 
        />
        <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category 
  android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

The content_main.xml comes here:

```
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/stopBtn"
                    android:layout_width="249dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:text="Stop PLayback"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/playBtn" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/playBtn"
                    android:layout_width="249dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:text="Play Recording"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/stopBtn"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/finishBtn" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/finishBtn"
                    android:layout_width="249dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:text="Finish Recording"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/playBtn"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/startBtn" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/startBtn"
                    android:layout_width="247dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:text="Start Recording"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/finishBtn"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/statusTextView"
                    android:layout_width="246dp"
                    android:layout_height="22dp"
                    android:text="Status"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/startBtn"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked for `CAMERA`, `WRITE_STORAGE` and `RECORD_AUDIO` permission but you don't asked for at your activity. take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

use:
`ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)` to check the status of the permission and compare it with `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` which mean that your permission is accepted like this :

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 100);
}
```

and inside the `onRequestPermissionsResult` do something like this :

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //do work
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the note. It makes sense that that this is the problem. Im not entirely sure how to implement your pieces of code though. But im researching for it now and getting clever.